# VirtualBox on Windows 10 Pro using BitLocker only allows 32-bit guests

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit, bitlocker

I've recently had my Windows 7 Professional laptop re-imaged to Windows 10 Enterprise as part of a Proof of Concept trial. BitLocker is enabled for encryption and I've re-installed VirtualBox which I'm a heavy user of, but I can now only seem to create 32-bit guest VM's, not 64-bit guests. When I was running Windows 7 pro, I had no problems with VirtualBox and could run 64-bit guest VM's without issue.

I've spent two days searching and trying things to address this, and the three common factors that seem to cause this are not the problem:

- **32-bit OS/CPU** - My laptop and O/S is 64-bit
- **Virtualization disabled in the BIOS** - I've checked and it's still enabled in the BIOS
- **Hyper-V enabled in Windows 10** - I've fully disabled Hyper-V through *Turn Features On or Off*

I use Windows 10 Pro on my home PC without BitLocker and can run 64-bit hosts just fine so not sure if BitLocker is the cause of this or something else. Can anyone suggest what else could be the cause of this?

Edit: Screengrab:

[image]

Comment: Why did you enable Hyper-V in the first place? Could you take a screen of the System Settings dialog (Win+Pause/Break) and add it? What version of VirutalBox are you running?

Comment: I didn't, it was already enabled in the initial Windows 10 build put together by the techs. I'm running the latest VirtualBox version 5.1.24. Screenshot attached.

Comment: Check with [SecurAble](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm) whether hardware virtualization is really enabled.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB, interestingly it reports hardware virtualization is not available. I've disabled, rebooted, and re-enabled virtualization in the Bios but ti still reports it as not being available.  Can;t understand it, it worked just fine on Windows 7,...

Comment: You can also look in Task Manager in Windows 10, in the CPU usage view. Please check (in console) `bcdedit /enum` for `hypervisorlaunchtype` attributes.

Comment: Virtualization Shows as `Enabled` in Task manager. `hypervisorlaunchtype` is set to Off.

Comment: Do you have any other virtualization software installed, like Intel HAXM?

Comment: Nothing at all, only VirtualBox. It's still a fairly bare since I got it back, except for reinstalling my common used apps - Office, Visual Studio and a few other small pieces of software, but no other virtualization software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved! It seems Windows Credential Guard was the root cause of this! Apparently it uses virtualization in some way?

Following step 4 in this VMWare KB article on my laptop and rebooting allowed me to run 64-bit VM's again.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361